# How to remove date, author and comment count from Chameleon search results page

Tags: themes, search

I would like to remove the following from the search results page, I'm using the ET Chameleon theme which doesn't have a search.php file in the editor section. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Posted by auscov on Feb 22, 2013 in | 0 comments
```

Comment: You should probably ask on Elegant Theme's Forum. Not all of us here have an account on ET.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that - I thought perhaps it might be a Theme related thing - perhaps other themes not by ET do the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the theme doesn't have a `search.php` file, `index.php` will be used.

> #### [Template_Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Search_Result_display)
>
> Template file used to render a Search Results Index page
>
> 1. **search.php**
> 2. **index.php**

*[update]*
Use the following to print the current template being used to render a page:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'so_9405896_the_content_filter', 20, 1 );

function so_9405896_the_content_filter( $content ) 
{
    if( is_admin() || !current_user_can( 'delete_plugins' ) ) 
        return $content;

    global $template;
    $the_templ =  '<strong style="background-color: #CCC;padding:10px">TEMPLATE = ' 
                  . basename( $template ) . '</strong><br />';  

    $content = sprintf( $the_templ . '%s', $content );

    return $content;
}
```

Which results in:

> [image: output template name to content]

Comment: Thanks that put me on the right track, the Index.php file pointed me to the PostInfo.php file which is where the rendering was being done. Thanks again!